# How open remote xml file in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Need help with nokogiri gem

When I open XML file through HTTPS

`No such file or directory error - https://mysecret.link?username=name&password=pass`

raises

```
source = open('https://mysecret.link?username=name&password=pass')
data = Nokogiri::XML(source)
```

Answer (score 10):

Did you `require 'open-uri'`? Otherwise `open` doesn't work with remote files.

```
>> open("http://google.com")
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - http://google.com
...
>> require 'open-uri' #=> true
>> open("http://google.com") #=> #<File:/tmp/open-uri20111215-27666-1jeeiqo>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'net/https'

url = URI.parse("https://address")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
response = http.start {|http| http.request(request) }
```